# Compact surfaces without conjugate points

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, hyperbolic-geometry

I've asked this question ([Surfaces without conjugate points](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/335165/surfaces-without-conjugate-points)) and received an attentive answer from user67582. The answer made me see that I should ask better. So i'm trying again here.

I'm trying to understand some aspects of the geodesics of **compact surfaces** without conjugate points and the following question came out: consider the 2-torus with negative constant curvature, its universal covering $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ with the covering metric and two geodesics in the covering wich are asymptotic to each other in the "future". It is true that the distance between these two geodesic increases monotonically in the "past", because of the negative curvature (see the figure).

[image: geodesics "approach" on future and "deviate" on the past]

I'm trying to see if this is true for universal coverings of compact surfaces **without conjugate points**. To be more precise, consider two geodesics wich are asymptotic to each other on the "future" on the universal coverig of a compact surface (2-torus, 3 torus etc). Is it true that the distance between them does not decrease on the past? I was thinking the following: if it was false, something like the following should happen:

[image: the distance on the past does not increase monotonically]

Perhaps it is possible to use some "shortcut" argument to prove this is impossible (if the result I want is true...) but I'm not able to construct "the smart shortcut", perhaps using the fact that the "upper" geodesic approaches a little bit to the "bottom" geodesic before the local maximum as we see in the figure. My idea lies on the fact that the "no conjugate points" conditions implies that on the universal covering every geodesic is minimizing. The fact that in the universal covering we have some control of the "periodicity" of the metric could give some hint too.

Thanks a lot on advance!

Answer (score 2):

firstly I just want to point out that the universal cover of the two holed torus (and in fact of the $n$-holed torus where $n>1$) is not $\mathbb{R}^2$ but the upper half plane (I'm going to denote this as $\mathcal{H}$) equipped with the Poincare metric: $g_{x+iy} = \frac{dxdy}{y^2}$.

Your first picture is a little misleading, since the geodesics on the upper half plane are precisely vertical lines and semi-circles with centre on the real axis. If we try and draw two geodesics which asymptote towards each other, say the semicircle centred at $0$ and of radius $1$ and the vertical line at $1$, we see that although they appear to asymptote towards each other as we approach the point $1$, the metric is actually blows up as $y\rightarrow 0$, so the actual distance between these two geodesics is heading to infinity. So, I don't think that there actually exists a pair of geodesics on $\mathcal{H}$ which asymptote towards each other.

Comment: Hi Daniel, thaks for the attention and for the pointing out about the covering. It seems to me that on the hyperbolic half plane, two vertical lines are asymptotic at the future and they deviate on the past, isn't it? At least I could see that they are asymptotic on the future, comparing the arcs joining the same height of both with the horizontal segments joining them.

Comment: My apologies matgaio, you are correct.If we take two vertical lines: $\gamma_1(t) = it$ and $\gamma_2(t) = 1+it$ say, we know that the distance between them will be $\rho(\gamma_1(t),\gamma_2(t) = 2\tanh^{-1}(|\frac{\gamma_1(t)-\gamma_2(t)}{\gamma_1(t)-\bar{\gamma_2(t)}} = 2\tanh^{-1}\frac{1}{1+4t^2}$ whci

Comment: My apologies matgaio, you are absolutely correct.If we take two vertical lines: $\gamma_1(t) = it$ and $\gamma_2(t) = 1+it$ say, we know that the distance between them will be $\rho(\gamma_1(t),\gamma_2(t)) = 2\tanh^{-1}(|\frac{\gamma_1(t)-\gamma_2(t)}{\gamma_1(t)-\bar{\gamma_2(t)}|)} = 2\tanh^{-1}(\frac{1}{1+4t^2})$ which heads to zero as $t$ heads to infinity and infinity as $t$ heads to zero. Incidentally, since $tanh^{-1}(\frac{1}{1+4t^2})$ increases monotonically as we approach zero from above, I think this answers your original question?

Comment: assuming that you are considering compact surfaces with their constant curvature metrics. Also disregard the first comment, I'm new at this mathoverflow thing, :)